# Rails -TypeError: can't cast ActionController::Parameters to text

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm developing a website using jQuery Preview to fetch the title, description or favction_url of any link.

jQuery Preview: https://github.com/embedly/jquery-preview/

My **links controller** has this code:

```
class LinksController < ApplicationController
    before_action :find_link, :only => [:edit, :update, :destroy]

    def index
        @links = Link.all
    end

    def new
        @link = Link.new
    end

    def create
        @link = Link.new(:content => link_params, :title => params[:title], :description => params[:description], :favicon_url => params[:favicon_url])

        if @link.save
            redirect_to root_path
        else
            render :new
        end
    end

    def edit
    end

    def update

        if @link.update_attributes(link_params)
            redirect_to root_path
        else
            render :edit
        end
    end

    def destroy
        @link.destroy

        redirect_to root_path
    end

private

    def link_params
        params.require(:link).permit(:content)
    end

    def find_link
        @link = Link.find(params[:id])
    end
end
```

And in my **views/links/new.html.erb** has this code:

```
<script>
    // Set up preview.
    $('#url').preview({key:'key'})

    // On submit add hidden inputs to the form.
    $('form').on('submit', function(){
      $(this).addInputs($('#url').data('preview'));
      return true;
    });
</script>

<h1>Share Link</h1>
<%= simple_form_for @link do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :content, :input_html => {:id => "url"} %>
    <div class="selector-wrapper"></div>
    <%= f.button :submit, :disable_with => "Submiting...", :class => "btn btn-primary btn-large" %>
<% end %>
```

But when I click submit, I got an error :

**TypeError: can't cast ActionController::Parameters to text: INSERT INTO "links" ("content", "created_at", "description", "favicon_url", "title", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)**

And it marked this line of links controller code:

```
if @link.save
```

Can anyone help me? Thank you.

The parameters I got is like following, except **content**, others are from jQuery Preview:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", 

"authenticity_token"=>"NDqZbleBkEEZzshRlTM+d6GZdVEGAoO1W/mp7B68ZZ0=", 

"link"=>{"content"=>"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20815513/rails-typeerror-cant-cast-actioncontrollerparameters-to-text/20815623?noredirect=1#20815623"}, 

"commit"=>"submit", 

"original_url"=>"http%3A//stackoverflow.com/questions/20815513/rails-typeerror-cant-cast-actioncontrollerparameters-to-text/20815623%3Fnoredirect%3D1%2320815623", 

"url"=>"http%3A//stackoverflow.com/questions/20815513/rails-typeerror-cant-cast-actioncontrollerparameters-to-text", 

"type"=>"html", 

"provider_url"=>"http%3A//stackoverflow.com", 

"provider_display"=>"stackoverflow.com", "provider_name"=>"Stackoverflow", 

"favicon_url"=>"http%3A//cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico", 

"title"=>"Rails%20-TypeError%3A%20can%27t%20cast%20ActionController%3A%3AParameters%20to%20text", 

    "description"=>"I%27m%20developing%20a%20website%20using%20jQuery%20Preview%20to%20fetch%20the%20title%2C%20description%20or%20favction_url%20of%20any%20link.", 

"thumbnail_url"=>"http%3A//cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png%3Fv%3Dfde65a5a78c6", 

"author_name"=>"", 

"author_url"=>"", 

"media_type"=>"", 

"media_html"=>"", 

"media_width"=>"", 

"media_height"=>""}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `create` action you're trying to assign `link_params` hash as value for `content` which expects text.

With the call to `Link.new(...)` passing in attributes you are mass assigning attributes, and with Rails4 strong parameters you need to add all the attributes to the `permit` list that you will be mass assigning.

Update the `create` and `link_params` method definition as follows:

```
# app/controllers/links_controller.rb

def create
    @link = Link.new(link_params)

    if @link.save
        redirect_to root_path
    else
        render :new
    end
end

private

def link_params
    params.require(:link).permit(:content, :title, :description, :favicon_url)
end
```

**Update:** Merge certain attributes from the parameter hash and merge them to `params[:link]`

```
# app/controllers/links_controller

private

def link_params
  # Select parameters you need to merge
  params_to_merge = params.select { |k, v| ['title', 'description', 'favicon_url'].include?(k) }
  params.require(:link).permit(:content).merge(params_to_merge)
end
```

Comment: Thank you, but the parameters I got not like this. Except :content, others are from jQuery Preview, and they are'nt under :link. For easy to read, I put the all parameters I got above. I want to know how to write code for the other parameters except params[:link][:content].

Comment: You need to merge all the parameters to `params[:link]` so that they can be permitted in the mass assignment.  If you cannot modify the view to include these parameters within your `link` form then this should be done in your controller.

Comment: Thank you very much. But How can I merge all the parameters to params[:link]? I found some posts, but I don't know how to appply to my application. Sorry, I'm a very beginner.

Comment: @user3087000, please see the update.  Note that `params_to_merge` hash should include all the attributes that you need to allow for mass assignment, so make sure to select all the attributes that you need in the `params.select`.