# Rails - How can I replace these special character?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm developing a website using jQuery Preview to fetch the title, description or favction_url of any link.

jQuery Preview: https://github.com/embedly/jquery-preview/

My **links controller** has this code:

```
class LinksController < ApplicationController
    before_action :find_link, :only => [:edit, :update, :destroy]

    def index
        @links = Link.all
    end

    def new
        @link = Link.new
    end

    def create
        @link = Link.new(link_params)

        if @link.save
            redirect_to root_path
        else
            render :new
        end
    end

    def edit
    end

    def update

        if @link.update_attributes(link_params)
            redirect_to root_path
        else
            render :edit
        end
    end

    def destroy
        @link.destroy

        redirect_to root_path
    end

private

    def link_params
        params_to_merge = params.select { |k, v| ['title', 'description', 'favicon_url'].include?(k) }
        params.require(:link).permit(:content).merge(params_to_merge)

    end

    def find_link
        @link = Link.find(params[:id])
    end
end
```

And in my **views/links/new.html.erb** has this code:

```
<script>
    // Set up preview.
    $('#url').preview({key:'key'})

    // On submit add hidden inputs to the form.
    $('form').on('submit', function(){
      $(this).addInputs($('#url').data('preview'));
      return true;
    });
</script>

<h1>Share Link</h1>
<%= simple_form_for @link do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :content, :input_html => {:id => "url"} %>
    <div class="selector-wrapper"></div>
    <%= f.button :submit, :disable_with => "Submiting...", :class => "btn btn-primary btn-large" %>
<% end %>
```

The parameters I got is like following, except **content**, others are from jQuery Preview:

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", 

"authenticity_token"=>"NDqZbleBkEEZzshRlTM+d6GZdVEGAoO1W/mp7B68ZZ0=", 

"link"=>{"content"=>"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20815513/rails-typeerror-cant-cast-actioncontrollerparameters-to-text/20815623?noredirect=1#20815623"}, 

"commit"=>"submit", 

"original_url"=>"http%3A//stackoverflow.com/questions/20815513/rails-typeerror-cant-cast-actioncontrollerparameters-to-text/20815623%3Fnoredirect%3D1%2320815623", 

"url"=>"http%3A//stackoverflow.com/questions/20815513/rails-typeerror-cant-cast-actioncontrollerparameters-to-text", 

"type"=>"html", 

"provider_url"=>"http%3A//stackoverflow.com", 

"provider_display"=>"stackoverflow.com", "provider_name"=>"Stackoverflow", 

"favicon_url"=>"http%3A//cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico", 

"title"=>"Rails%20-TypeError%3A%20can%27t%20cast%20ActionController%3A%3AParameters%20to%20text", 

    "description"=>"I%27m%20developing%20a%20website%20using%20jQuery%20Preview%20to%20fetch%20the%20title%2C%20description%20or%20favction_url%20of%20any%20link.", 

"thumbnail_url"=>"http%3A//cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon@2.png%3Fv%3Dfde65a5a78c6", 

"author_name"=>"", 

"author_url"=>"", 

"media_type"=>"", 

"media_html"=>"", 

"media_width"=>"", 

"media_height"=>""}
```

For instance, please see "title" or "description" above, I want to know how can I replace the special characters with original look? For example, "**%3A**" is "**:**".

Can anyone help me? Thanks a lot.

**Update:**

undefined method `tr' for ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess:0x007ff82585b950

```
def link_params
    params.each { |k,v| params[k] = CGI.unescape(v) }
    params_to_merge = params.select { |k, v| ['title', 'description', 'favicon_url'].include?(k) }
    params.require(:link).permit(:content).merge(params_to_merge)
end
```

And it marked this line as error:

```
params.each { |k,v| params[k] = CGI.unescape(v) }
```

Comment: I think rails will decode them for you automatically.

Comment: I'm guessing that something in your JavaScript is URL-encoding those strings before sending anything to the server. Where does `addInputs` come from? What does `$('#url').data('preview')` look like?

Comment: Refined the answer, hope it work for you now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`CGI.unescape`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/cgi/rdoc/CGI.html#method-c-unescape) or [`URI.unescape`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI/Escape.html#method-i-unescape) for that, but note that `URI.unescape` is obsolete since `Ruby 1.9.2` because of problems with its sibling  `URI.escape`, so I used the CGI one here.

```
require 'cgi'

params.each do |key, value|
  if value.kind_of?(Hash)
    value.each {|k,v| value[k] = CGI.unescape(v)}
  else
    params[key] = CGI.unescape(value)
  end
end
```

The above code iterates through the params hash, and checks each value of it if it contains another hash.

1. If so it loops through this hash and unescape its values.
2. If the value of the params is not a hash (the else statement) it unescape it and save it to the params at the relevant key.

Comment: Please check the update I made above. I got an error.  Thank you.

Comment: Didn't get what you mean? Is the code work but not returning what you expect?

Comment: Can you explain the concept behind this code for me? Sorry, I can't clearly know what it does. Why should check a value if is Hash, and Why can't I leave one of two alone without if statement? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Mainly I can't clearly know is this two line:if value.kind_of?(Hash)
        value.each {|k,v| value[k] = CGI.unescape(v)}

Comment: Added an explanation.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44099/discussion-between-wazery-and-user3087000)

Comment: Thanks:) Clear explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is **`URI.unescape(str)`**, e.g.:

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'uri'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> URI.unescape 'http%3A//stackoverflow.com/questions/20815513/rails-typeerror-cant-cast-actioncontrollerparameters-to-text/20815623%3Fnoredirect%3D1%2320815623'
=> "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20815513/rails-typeerror-cant-cast-actioncontrollerparameters-to-text/20815623?noredirect=1#20815623"
```

The long answer is that those shouldn't be escaped to begin with. Can you post the HTML that `simple_form_for` creates? Also, a snippet of HTML that is generated for a scraped link would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are trying to decode url

```
require 'uri'

URI.unescape("Rails%20-TypeError%3A%20can%27t%20cast%20ActionController%3A%3AParameters%20to%20text")

# "Rails -TypeError: can't cast ActionController::Parameters to text"
```