# what is the solution with rails in adding something to a table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I am new to rails

so I am doing a basic application that manage tasks

I have created the create method to add a new task

and a form in the index.html.erb file
but when i insert a task in the form it shows an error

the tasks controller file:

```
class TasksController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @tasks = Task.all
  end

  def create
    Task.create params[:task]
    redirect_to :back
  end
end
```

the index.html.erb file:

```
    "<h1>Tasks</h1>
<%= form_for Task.new do |f| %>
<%= f.label :task %>
<%= f.text_field :task %>
<%= f.submit %>
<% end %>

<ul>
<% for task in @tasks %>
<li><%= task.task %></li>
<% end %>
</ul>"
```

and the error is:

```
undefined method `task' for #<Class:0xbd75770>
Extracted source (around line #7):
6 def create
7 Task.create params[:task]
8 redirect_to :back
9 end

app/controllers/tasks_controller.rb:7:in `create'
```

what is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem in:

```
t.task = Task.task
```

Task class has no method task.
Use `t = Task.new(task_params)` or `t.task = task_params['task']`

**Updated**:
Add to your controller:

```
def create
   @task = Task.new task_params
   @task.save
   ... etc
end

def task_params
  params.require(:task).permit(:task)
end
```

Comment: About this errors look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20815513/rails-typeerror-cant-cast-actioncontrollerparameters-to-text - i think you need use strong parameters